# PCF Config server Authentication issues

Tags: spring-boot, pcf, pcfdev

I am following the below to set up a config server in PCF and access the application in PCF.

https://github.com/pcf-guides/gs-configuration-server

I have added the config server from the PCF marketplace and it is bind with the app.

The config server is pointed to the following Git repository:

https://github.com/pcf-guides/configuration-server-config-repo.git

The VCAP_SERVICES is like below :

```
 "p-config-server": [
  {
  "binding_name": null,
  "credentials": {
   "access_token_uri": "https://p-spring-cloud- 
  services.uaa.run.pivotal.io/oauth/token",
   "client_id": "p-config-server-d837bb39-4cf1-47ce-994b-03257852a7f6",
   "client_secret": "XXsWzX6IhKME",
   "uri": "https://config-9f0e115f-dbb0-42e8-981a-e70e2cd62570.cfapps.io"
  },
  "instance_name": "sconfigserver",
  "label": "p-config-server",
  "name": "sconfigserver",
  "plan": "trial",
  "provider": null,
   "syslog_drain_url": null,
 "tags": [
 "configuration",
 "spring-cloud"
```

Whenever I am trying to access the application authentication error is coming :
Full authentication is required to access this resource.

I dont have any security configuration in the application.

Comment: Hi Souvikc, did you find any solution of this? I am facing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your application.properties file, you should add the following

**management.security.enabled=false**

This will disable security altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my main application class and worked fine for me

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class , ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```